# Sending information to another website

Tags: php

How would I send information from one site to another and filling in the form?

For example, let's say I have a Minecraft server, and I'd like to have a form where a player can enter their name on my site. After entering their name and pressing enter, they are sent to the other site where their name are auto filled.

Here's a good example. On [this site](http://www.obsidiancraft.com/) you can enter your name where it says "vote for diamonds". (You can enter anything), after doing that and clicking next - they provide buttons for the voting sites. Once they click, they're sent to the next website with they're name already filled and they are on the next page (After the user would enter  their name). How can I do this for my site? I can't think of a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `action` attribute to specify where the form data should be procesed:

```
<form action="http://othersite.com/processor.php" method="post">
   <!-- Form elements go here -->
</form>
```

I assumed that is what you meant. If you are looking for the server to send collected data to another server, you will need to use cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php